# How to add subview to stackview in table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, null, stackview

I am in need to add the label as subview to UIStackView in table view cell.

I have created label as

```
let nameLabel=UILabel()
nameLabel.text=names[indexPath.row]
```

Where name is an array which is a type of `String`

My code is

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{
            let names=["Amutha","Priya","Amuthapriya","Priyasri","Kavisha"]
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
            {
                return names.count
            }
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->
                UITableViewCell
            {
                let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! ViewCell
                for name in names
                {
                    let nameLabel=UILabel()
                    nameLabel.text=name
                    cell.nameStackView!.addSubview(nameLabel)

                }

                return cell
            }
}
```

Why I am getting a null pointer exception when I add a label to stackview?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Show `ViewCell` code

Comment: When using `UIStackView`, always use `addArrangedSubview()` and add to its arranged subviews array instead of the regular `addSubview()`, since it manages its subviews itself based on the configuration.

Comment: @LokSN You are correct. But this is not the reason of the crash

Comment: Didn't mean it is, just had a point to make. Judging from the comments on the answers, it's probably due to the cell's `nameStackView ` being nil

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cell.nameStackView!.addSubview(nameLabel)
```

To

```
cell.nameStackView!.addArrangedSubview(nameLabel)
```

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: ```Unexpectedly found nill while unwrapping an optional value``` on this line

Comment: I think you did not connect `nameStackView` IBOutlet with Storyboard or xib file. Please recheck it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to add UIStackView as per your need.

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
let subtitleLabel = UILabel()

lazy var titleStackView: UIStackView = {

    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabel.text = "Good Morning"
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Regular", size: 12.0)

    subtitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    subtitleLabel.text = "--"
    subtitleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    subtitleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0).isActive = true
    subtitleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "DublinSpurs", size: 20.0)

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [subtitleLabel])
    stackView.axis = .vertical/.horizontal
    return stackView
}()
```

Also try replacing

```
for name in names
{
    let nameLabel=UILabel()
    nameLabel.text=name
    cell.nameStackView!.addSubview(nameLabel)
}
```

with

```
let nameLabel=UILabel()
nameLabel.text = names[indexPath.row]
cell.nameStackView!.addSubview(nameLabel)
```

Comment: I have to dynamically add array items to stack view as label

Comment: You shouldn't be using `addSubview()` to add to a stack view

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
let nameLabel = UILabel()

cell.nameStackView.addArrangedSubview(nameLabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `nameStackView` in storyboard or xib, make sure the `IBOutlet` is connected properly. If you have created the `nameStackView` programmatically make sure it is initialised.

And remove all existing labels from the stackview, else you'll have duplicate labels on each scroll

```
class ViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    //Make sure IBOutlet is connected properly
    @IBOutlet weak var nameStackView: UIStackView!
}
```

ViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! ViewCell
     for name in names
     {
        cell.nameStackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach { cell.nameStackView.removeArrangedSubview($0) }
        let nameLabel=UILabel()
        nameLabel.text=name
        cell.nameStackView.addSubview(nameLabel)

     }
     return cell
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the stackview and label in your `ViewCell` class.

```
class ViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return label
    }()
    let nameStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        return stackView
    }()
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super .init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.configureStackView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configureStackView()
    {
        addSubview(nameStackView)
        nameStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nameStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        nameStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        nameStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        nameStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        nameStackView.addArrangedSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameStackView.topAnchor, 
        constant:10).isActive = true
        nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameStackView.leadingAnchor, 
        constant:10).isActive = true
        nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameStackView.trailingAnchor, 
        constant:-10).isActive = true
        nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameStackView.bottomAnchor, 
        constant:-10).isActive = true
    }
}
```

This code is in case you didn't create your `stackview` in storyboard.

Now in your `ViewController` class, add the following code in your `cellForRowAt` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->
                UITableViewCell
{
    let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! ViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = names[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Hope, this solution works for you.